How to connect to ignite apache Database using typescript?
This is the code
import * as mysql from 'mysql';

async function connectAndQueryDatabase(): Promise<void> {
    // Database connection configuration
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: '10.10.10.10',
        database: 'DBNAME'
    });

try {
     await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.connect((err) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log('Connected to database');
            resolve();
        });
    });

     const queryResults = await new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM TABLE', (err, results, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(results);
        });
    });

    console.log('Query results:', queryResults);

} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
} finally {
     await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.end((err) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log('Database connection closed');
            resolve();
        });
    });
}}


// Call the function to connect and query the database
connectAndQueryDatabase();

This is the error am getting
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true

Am not sure whats library I have to use to connect because we have to give only the URL to connect using SQL client. Do we have a JDBC driver to create a connection with the DB?

Ignite isn’t compatible with MySQL, so their driver won’t work. I would suggest you start with the documentation. In short, you’ll need to download the Ignite library and port your code to use that.
I don’t know much about typescript, but if you can use JDBC or ODBC drivers, that would be an option, too as long as you don’t need to use key-value APIs.

In Java, it works for sure but not getting a solution on TS. Can you help with referring some code, that would be great.

The documentation link in my answer includes a lot of code. Which specific part are you having difficulty with?
